# Send GPS coordinates to Android emulator using DDMS, telnet or any other means

Tags: android, gps, xamarin.android, telnet, ddms

DDMS is not able to send location to the emulator. I have tried sending just the location from DDMS but still the emulator is not able to receive location.  Nothing appears on the DDMS log when I click the Send button.

I tried sending geo fix from telnet which returns OK but doesn't actually update the location, or if it does I can't read it via my application.

The application works properly in the device, is able to capture test location details but not able to capture location data sent to the emulator either via DDMS or telnet.

I am testing on Android 2.2 emulator. Can anyone let me know what is wrong?

My app (below) is written in C# using Mono for Android and may need fixing (I'm a newbie to all things Android so I could have missed something).  OnLocationChanged(Location location) just doesn't seem to fire at all, as if the listener isn't properly defined.  Any help appreciated.

Note:  The first time I run this Activity the LocationManager.GetLastKnownLocation is null but the test provider stuff isn't accessed.   When I run it again GetLastKnowLocation is still null but the test provider stuff is accessed and set.  Weird.

```
[Activity(Label = "Location Demo")]
public class LocationActivity : Activity, ILocationListener
{
    private TextView _locationText;
    private LocationManager _locationManager;
    private StringBuilder _builder;
    private Geocoder _geocoder;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LocationActivity);
        _geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        _locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextView1);
        _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);

        if (_locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation("gps") == null)
        {
            _locationManager.AddTestProvider("gps", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 0, 5);
            _locationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled("gps", true);
            Location loc = new Location("gps");
            loc.Latitude = 50;
            loc.Longitude = 50;
            _locationManager.SetTestProviderLocation("gps", loc);
        }
        Location lastKnownLocation = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation("gps");

        if (lastKnownLocation != null)
        {
            _locationText.Text += string.Format("Last known location, lat: {0}, long: {1}", lastKnownLocation.Latitude, lastKnownLocation.Longitude);
        }
        else
        {
            _locationText.Text += string.Format("Last location unknown");
        }
        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 2, this);
    }
    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        _locationText.Text += string.Format("Location updated, lat: {0}, long: {1}", location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
    }
    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider){}
    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider){}
    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Android.Locations.Availability availability, Bundle extras){}

}
```

Kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/users/170333/greg-shackles for getting me this far.

Comment: What happens if you remove the test provider code? That might be overriding the location data you're providing.

Comment: Removing the test provider means GetLastKnownLocation always returns  null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved this.  When the emulator is launched by VS2010 (i.e. F5, start debugging) it does not behave as expected.  Launch the emulator externally using AVD.exe, start a virtual device and deploy the app. to it (using F5, start debugging) and everything works fine.

Why starting the emulator from within or outside VS2010 should make any difference is a mystery I am able to live with.  Thanks to everyone for their helpful suggestions.

Comment: Actually, DDMS still doesn't send GPS coords but telnet does.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be with how you're calling [`RequestLocationUpdates()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29). That third parameter is the minimum distance the device needs to move before you get updates, so you're telling the system to only send updates after the device has moved 2 meters. If it works on a real device, it's probably because you moved more than 6 feet. :)

Try starting with `RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this)`. That will start a stream of updates on a real device, but only one when you press 'Send' in DDMS. Once that works, I would work back from there on how often you get updates.

Also, `GetLastKnownLocation()` is always null when you start the emulator. It's better for devices since it can send you the network location as a starting estimate, or the GPS location if another program was using it recently.

**EDIT**

It could also be a permissions issue. Normally you need to alter `AndroidManifest.xml` to get GPS access. The line is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#Permission).

Comment: Sorry, the app doesn't work on a real device - I only have an emulator to try it on.  Changing RequestLocationUpdates as advised makes no difference the location is still not being updated.    GetLastKnownLocation being null on start of the emulator makes sense.  Another thing to note is that this development is done entirely on Windows, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER is not a valid option using Mono for Android through VS2010.  There are very few  samples of Mono for Android with VS2010 apart from what's on Xaramin.com.

Comment: @cymorg Updated with another possibility. Also, it's not the main issue, and I don't have any experience with C# or Mono, but I think the GPS provider constant for you would be [this one](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=F%3aAndroid.Locations.LocationManager.GpsProvider).

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml has correct user-permission - still no joy.  Beginning to think the emulator is incapable of running correctly on Windows7.

Comment: The emulator GPS and DDMS and Win7 all worked together for me on [this small project](https://github.com/stevehb/MyTwenty). I'm just using the usual Java + Eclipse setup, and I followed [Google's instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).

Comment: Have you tried adding debug statements to `OnProviderDisabled()`, `OnProviderEnabled()`, and `OnStatusChanged()`. I would also check the output of [`GetAllProviders(false)`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Locations.LocationManager.GetProviders(System.Boolean)) to make sure GPS isn't disabled for some weird reason.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
_locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 2, this);
```

function before doing any location operations, like below:

```
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LocationActivity);
_geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
_locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextView1);
_locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
_locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 2, this); //this will cause updated location to be retrieved from telnet
```

Note: Its normal that program works after the first run, so that after the first run your application could get the initial updated location from telnet and that will be enough to not throws an exception

Comment: Nothing, nada, nil, null, nought.  Telnet message is sent OK but the app can't read it from the emulator.  I'm losing the will to resolve this and starting to think about workarounds, which I despise as it's always better face one's troubles head on.

Answer (score 0):

Does your emulated android image have GPS hardware? The description in the emulator should have "hw.gps=yes".

I had the same symptoms before recreating a new image with the right (emulated) hardware.  I found a simple web page that displays the [current location](https://phil-wise.com/locator/) was handy when debugging the emulation environment.